# Non aggregate functions, relational algebra

Tags: relational-algebra

How can we translate the non aggregate functions of Structured Query Language into relational algebra expressions?! I know how to express the aggregate functions, but what about the non aggregate functions?! 
e.g How can we write the Year( a date format column) function?! Just Year(date)?

select e.name,year(e.dateOfEmployment) from Employees e

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

(This is a very reasonable question, I don't understand why it should get downvoted.)

The "Relational" in RA means expressing functions as mathematical relations -- using a set-theoretic approach. (It *doesn't* mean, as often thought, relating one table or datum to another as in "Entity Relational" modelling.) I can't grab a very succinct reference for this off the top of my head, but start here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation and follow the links.

How does this get to answer your question in context of a practical RA? Have a look at this:
http://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/~hugh/TTM/APPXA.pdf, especially the section Treating Operators as Relations.

See how the relations PLUS and SQRT can be 'applied' (using COMPOSE, which is a shorthand for Natural JOIN and PROJECT) to behave as a function.

For your specific question, you need a relation with two attributes (type Date and Year).